# Clang parser - ignore directive #ifdef, parse everything

Tags: c, parsing, clang, llvm-clang

I need to find calls of some functions in C source codes. I'm using [Clang Python bindings](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/bindings/python) for this.

The problem is, that this parser ignores code inside of "inactive" `#ifdef` directives. I understand, that this behaviour is correct (if the condition result is False), but now I need it simply to find all the calls, because of some automatic editing.

---

#### Example:

```
#define CONST2

#ifdef CONST
f90()
#endif

f90()

#ifdef CONST2
f90()
#endif
```

The parser will find just the second and the third call of the function `f90()`, but not the first one, because `CONST` is undefined. But I need Clang to find even the first one.

---

Is there any way to change this Clang behaviour?

#### EDIT:

I **don't** have a problem with source codes. The problem is in the settings of Clang parser - I need it simply to parse the WHOLE code, regardless of unmet conditions.

#### EDIT 2:

Ok, I don't think there's a bug in Clang... My question is, if there's some setting (possibly some flag) in Clang, so it'll ignore `#ifdef` conditions during code parsing.

Comment: You need to fix the automatic editing, or else you need to define `CONST`.

Comment: @Ben The problem is not in the parsed source code. I simply need Clang to parse ALL the code, regardless of any unmet conditions in it.

Comment: Might you be able to work around it by searching for #if*def calls and trying to define them all in your call to clang? It's would be a hack.

Comment: It's a virtual certainty that you don't want to do that. Really you need to find out the reason why it's working for others but not for you, i.e. what you have actually done wrong. But without knowing what your actual problem is I can't help.

Comment: @Eenoku Can you clarify what you need? Because as you wrote your question, most programs would become invalid due to include guards being defeated by your technique.

Comment: @Eenoku Have you found a better answer than the accepted one?

Comment: @Interlooper Quite a long time ago... :-) But I started using [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) IDE since and it seems to cover my needs pretty well. Hopefully it'll do the work for you, too.

Comment: @Eenoku Do you know what CLion uses for static code analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to make most C parsers look att all the code regardless of preprocessor directives. There may be exceptions, but clang isn't one of them.

The reason is the way the compiler works in two separate steps. First the pre-processor parses the pre-processor directives. The pre-processor knows nothing of the C syntax, it only knows the pre-processor syntax.

Then the preprocessed code is processed by the compiler. The compiler knows everything about the C syntax and one of it's jobs is to find syntax errors.
If you would send it all code, the code that should have been removed by he pre-processor is likely to cause syntax errors.

I would recommend that you either re-think your solution entirely, or that you supplement what you have with a step that looks for calls hidden inside pre-processor directives. Unless the code is poorly designed, there should not be so many of those.

Note that since the pre-processor step can do code manipulation, it is very difficult to build a tool that can handle all possible cases.

Comment: This answer isn't right in theory, or for all possible tools, It is right for *almost* all the tools for processing C or C++ that have been built (and it is true I think for Clang).   There *are* tools that can parse the source code retaining the preprocessor directives  (see my bio for one) modulo some complications such as "the code in non-exercised arms has to be valid C code".   People violate that rule often in "#if 0" blocks which they use as bad comments, or to inclued a chunk of COBOL or other stupid nonsense.

Comment: @IraBaxter These tools also frequently choke on macros. For the same reason, C source indenters do not work reliably.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks. I didn't know anyone had gone through the trouble of writing such a tool. I've updated the wording of my answer.